# Beckhoff Twincat.ADS.dll and C#

Tags: c#, plc

I'm investigating the possibilities to control a Beckhoff PLC via C#. My main idea is to use a Raspberry Pi with Windows 10 IoT Core and to create a C# program. For now I have a small testprogram running using the TwinCat.Ads library but to get this to work I have to declare variables in the PLC which I read or write. This demands a basic CPU module of Beckhoff which are expensive.

I don't see if it's possible to only use a EK1100 module to directly read or write to the IO via the ADS library. Does anyone know if this is possible? It would make the PLC-hardware a lot cheaper and I can also start using Model Driven Development software which is the end goal of my investigation.

Thanks for your help

Some pieces of code of my first test:

```
  adsClient = new TcAdsClient();
  adsClient.Connect("5.51.69.60.1.1", 851);

  string result;
        var Handle =  adsClient.CreateVariableHandle("GVL_GENERAL.g_sMachineNumber");
        try
        {
            using (AdsStream adsStream = new AdsStream(30))
            {
                AdsBinaryReader reader = new AdsBinaryReader(adsStream);
                adsClient.Read(Handle, adsStream);
                result = reader.ReadPlcAnsiString(30);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The point of TwinCAT is to run the PLC on the same machine as your own code.  It does so by using the processor's Hypervisor capabilities to run the OS on top of a real-time kernel that implements the PLC.  The odds that this can work on an ARM core ought to be slim-to-none.  Directly talking to the EtherCAT bus is technically possible, the low-level frame is documented [here](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/18014402698815243.html&id=).  They may have a library to help you do this, give them a call.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to buy beckhoff hardware to run your experiments.

Just install the twincat engineering environment and you also get a local runtime which you can program and test.

Read and write IO's is possible through the ads protocol, also from a remote PC.

Installing the twincat runtime is also possible on arm, in fact Beckhoff has a whole set of arm CPU PLCs themselves.
I never tried on a Raspberry though..It would be interesting to know if it works under windows 10 iot.Let me know in the comment section pls.

What I know that works for sure on the raspberry, is Codesys V3, which is a very similar engineering environment as Twincat 3. 
You can download the special codesys  Raspberry pi image from their website.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I don't want to run the twincat runtime. There are examples on YT of using a modbus DLL, C# and just a Wago buscoupler. I would like to achieve something similar with the beckhoff Ek1100 which is kind of standard in the company.

The main reason, Beckhoff is very expensive with licenses for each add-on when products are sold. If I can use only the hardware with an embedded controller I expect we can save a lot of money. It's a proof of concept for a graduation project.

Comment: You need an Ethercat Master for that. Without an Ethercat Master you can't communicate with the EK1100 neither in c# nor with modbus..

Comment: P.S: In future use the comment section to add info to your question or edit your question directly instead of posting an answer to your question.